# android, zxing, styling the response

Tags: android, zxing

alright so I've searched for quite sometime on this and I can't seem to find just the kind of answer that answers my questions...so here goes nothing! And mind you, I'm new to android dev soooo I may have stupid questions that some of you may get irritated at, but we all have to learn some how right?

I'm trying to develop an application that will allow users to scan in a QR code and then display the information that is encoded into it in a nice organized way.

It seems like ZXing doesn't like the idea of integrating their code with other applications e.g. you have to use their application from the market and point to it via intents... well if I do it this way, can I decode the contents so that I can have access to the content and do as I want with it?

What would I have to include in my project from the ZXing folder that I downloaded to make it all work? And would I have to build all of the objects with in that folder in order to use them in my project?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

I have decided to go other routes.

Comment: I think I've been pretty clear: there's no problem integrating our code into your app. After all we open sourced it. It's the complete copy-and-paste of Barcode Scanner that's poor. That's what most are asking for -- the fastest thing they can copy. They're short on time or knowledge, but won't take the Intent route that needs almost no code, usually because it would hurt their monetization.  If you're substantially building your own app, cool. If you're saying you have no Android experience and asking this, I don't think that's you. Intents is really where you should be to start.

Answer (score 1):

The "Android way" is to do everything via intents.. However, zxing is a special case. You can follow the intent route, or you can (as it's apache licensed), download the source code and adapt as necessary. We did that for the game [Barcode Beasties](http://www.barcodebeasties.com) ( mandatory self promoting download link here : https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fawepark.android.barcodebeasties ) and that meant we could also brand the scan page as well.

If you want use the software integrated, then just download the source and either compile it as a library or just include it in your source folder as another folder.